# I'm trying to use parseint but it does not work

Tags: javascript, html, parseint

I'm writing a script and I want a H1 tag to increase with an input's value. But it doesn't work. I'm probably dumb, but I'm here cause I want help.

This is my code:

```js
var h1Value = 0;

function addFun() {
  var changeH1By = document.getElementById('input').value;
  parseInt('h1Value') + parseInt('changeH1By');
  document.getElementById('h1').innerHTML = h1Value;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="h1">0</h1>
<input type="number" id="input" value="1">
<button onclick="addFun()">Add</button>
```

As you probably see I'm using parseInt(), because else the h1 was "11". Like 1 + 1 = 11? Am I using the parseInt wrong or is something else wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: you're passing in string to the parseint function put in the variable instead

Answer (score 0):

- You were passing an string into `parseInt`, remove the quotes to pass the variable.
- You didn't assign the result of `parseInt('h1Value') + parseInt('changeH1By');`to any variable
- Instead off keeping track of `var h1Value`, lets use `document.getElementById('h1').innerHTML` to get the current value
- Removed `newValue` so we can set the new value instant as `innerHTML`

```js
function addFun() {
  var currentvalue = document.getElementById('h1').innerHTML;
  var changeH1By = document.getElementById('input').value;
  
  document.getElementById('h1').innerHTML = parseInt(currentvalue) + parseInt(changeH1By);
}
```

```html
<h1 id="h1">0</h1>
<input type="number" id="input" value="1">
<button onclick="addFun()">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the strings `"h1Value"` and `"changeH1By"` to `parseInt` and it's trying to parse those literal strings to integers. If you try logging the result of e.g. `parseInt("h1Value")` it evaluates to `NaN`, i.e. "not a number", which would give you a hint of where you're going wrong.

A working version of your code would be

```js
var h1Value = 0;
function addFun() {
  var changeH1By = document.getElementById('input').value;
  h1Value = h1Value + parseInt(changeH1By);
  document.getElementById('h1').innerHTML = h1Value;
}
```

The type of `h1Value` is already a number, so it doesn't need to be coerced into one, and instead of calling `parseInt` with the *literal string* "changeH1By", you'll need to give the actual *variable* as an argument. Also the line

```js
parseInt('h1Value') + parseInt('changeH1By');
```

doesn't do anything by itself, the javascript engine will just compute the value and throw it away, as you're not saving it into a variable etc.

Answer (score 0):

A clean way for coding that...

1. `<input..>` elements of `type="number"` have a `valueAsNumber` property
2. use `const` to avoid repeating the results of these interpretations

```js
const
  h1_element = document.getElementById('h1')
, changeH1By = document.getElementById('input')
  ;
function addFun()
  {
  h1_element.textContent = changeH1By.valueAsNumber
                         + parseInt(h1_element.textContent)
  }
```

```html
<h1 id="h1">0</h1>
<input type="number" id="input" value="1">
<button onclick="addFun()">Add</button>
```